# 'list index out of range' error when appending to a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a list (A) to create another list (B). If the entry in the list A is the same as the previous entry in list A, I want to append list B with the same value from the previous entry in list B. If the entry in list A is not the same, I'd like to increment the count in list B. For example, for

```
list A = ['2014-06-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-06-02', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03']
```

I would want

```
list B = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

I'm getting an 'list index out of range' error and I can't understand why.

```
list_of_dates = ['2014-06-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-06-02', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03']

case_day_count = [0]
for i in xrange(1,len(list_of_dates)): 
    if i == 1:
        continue
    if list_of_dates[i] == list_of_dates[(i-1)]:
        case_day_count.append(case_day_count[(i-1)])
    else:
        case_day_count.append(case_day_count[(i-1)]+1)
```

Comment: Lists are indexed starting from `0`, not `1`. Fix that and it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_day_count` has an initial length of 1 when you try to assign to `case_day_count[1]`, which would be the 2nd element of a 1-element list, so it causes an `IndexError`.

If you initialize `case_day_count` as:

```
case_day_count = [0, 0]
```

You will get your expected list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
import itertools
list_of_dates = ['2014-06-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-06-02',
                 '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03']

case_day_count = [0]
for (a,b) in itertools.izip(list_of_dates[:-1], list_of_dates[1:]):
    case_day_count.append(case_day_count[-1] + int(a != b))

print(case_day_count)
```

But it might not really be clear what's going on here.  Instead, this may be a better compromise:

```
import itertools
list_of_dates = ['2014-06-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-06-02',
                 '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-03']

case_day_count = [0]
for (a,b) in itertools.izip(list_of_dates[:-1], list_of_dates[1:]):
    last_count = case_day_count[-1]
    next_count = last_count + (1 if a != b else 0)
    case_day_count.append(next_count)

print(case_day_count)
```

Both produce `[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a little mistake here
you should remove the first if statement:

```
if i == 1:
        continue
```

I have removed it and got the expected result just as you wanted.

remember that list index starts with 0.
your statement says "skip the second element (index 1)". while you actually want to skip the first element (index 0).

since you are starting with second element (index 1), you do not need this if statement.